# Formatting a date with datetime.strptime()

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to create this 'alarmBot' using python and the Discord API. However, I can't seem to figure how get past this `ValueError` exception that I've created within the remind command. I've copied the entire code to show my imported libraries

NOTE: My token was there but I removed it obviously.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime
import asyncio

#/////////////////////// Welcome & Channel IDS ///////////////////////////////////


intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents = intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Alarmbot is now Ready.")
 
#///////////////////////// Command List !help /////////////////////////
@client.command()
async def info(ctx):
    await ctx.send("`Here are the following Commands:\n--------!create_reminder--------\n--------!delete_reminder--------`")

#////////////////////// Create Reminder ////////////////////////////
#CREATE DICTIONARY FOR ASYNCIO TIME FOR LONGER REMINDERS
#TO CREATE MUTIPLE REMINDERS CREATE A LIST WITH YOUR ID WITH THAT SPECIFIC NUMBER
#TO DELETE WHEN DELETE IS CALLED LIST OUT ALL ACTIVE REMINDERS WITH NUMBERS IN WHICH THEY WERE CREATED 
#GIVEN THE INTEGER DELETE THE APPRIOATE REMINDER

reminders = {}
format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"

@client.command()
async def remind(ctx, time: str, *, reminder: str):  
    reminder_message = f"{ctx.author.mention}, Here's your reminder: {reminder}"
    
    
    #Time Difference Calculations
    try:
        then = datetime.strptime(time, format)
        await ctx.send(f"Reminder set: {reminder}")
    except ValueError as e:
        await ctx.send("Please follow the formatting: %m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
    
    
    now = datetime.now()
    time_diff = (then - now).total_seconds()
    
    if (time_diff < 0):
        await ctx.send("Negative time value.")
    else:
    # Store the reminder in the reminders dictionary
        reminders[ctx.author.id] = (reminder_message, then)
        await asyncio.sleep(time_diff)
    
    # Check if the reminder still exists in the dictionary (not deleted)
    if ctx.author.id in reminders:
        del reminders[ctx.author.id]
        await ctx.send(reminder_message)

    
#/////////////////////////// Delete Reminder ////////////////////////
@client.command()
async def cancel(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id in reminders:
        del reminders[ctx.author.id]
        await ctx.send("Your reminder has been cancelled")
    else:
        await ctx.send("No Reminders Found.")

    
client.run(TOKEN)
```

I've been messing around with the formatting as I am not sure if I am using the `.strptime()` command correctly and additionally tested it outside the command in just another program. I think the error resolves around the given HH:MM being detected as a reminder variable.

```
DISCORD
INPUT: !remind 06/18/2023 21:07 this is a test
OUTPUT: Reminder set: 21:07 this is a test
```

The given output was before I moved the "Reminder set" part into the try statement.

```py
try:
        then = datetime.strptime(time, format)
        await ctx.send(f"Reminder set: {reminder}")
    except ValueError as e:
        await ctx.send("Please follow the formatting: %m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

EDIT: Just realized that I have the variable `then` in the `try` statement which means it cannot be accessed by `time_diff` but even with the variable moved out of `try` statement, the `ValueError` still happened.

Comment: I suspect the trailing text "this is a test" is part of the time string.  Are you stripping that part off?

Comment: @JohnGordon, don't believe I am how would I implement that?

Comment: If you're not stripping it off, then that is likely the problem.

Comment: One way is to split the message on spaces, and only accept the first two parts (in this case, `06/18/2023` and `21:07`)

Comment: Also, with that specific format string, you'll get an error if the user types a one-digit month, day, hour, or minute.